# A simple physics related algebra question.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, mathematical-physics

This is making me feel like an idiot. I'm given this answer for a question but I don't understand it.

$$y =\rm (-12.9\, m/s)(3.27\, s) + 1/2(9.81\, m/s^2)(3.27\, s)^2 = 105\, m = 0.11\, km$$

I punch these numbers into the calculator but I'm not getting $\rm105\, m$ but instead I'm getting $\rm(-42.183) + (52.449) = 10.266\, m$.

*Edit*: [Here is the full question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ib9nN.jpg)

Comment: [WolframAlpha agrees with you](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28-12.9%20m/s%29%283.27%20s%29%20%2b%201/2%289.81%20m/s%5E2%29%283.27%20s%29%5E2), so maybe there is an error in the question or maybe you copied the numbers wrong.

Comment: Just to clarify is this your formula: $y = (-12.9 \ ms^{-1}) \cdot(3.27 \ s) + \frac{1}{2} (9.81 \ ms^{-2})(3.27 \ s)^2$

Comment: Looks like the 105 is just $gt^2$, so I would say you are right.

Answer (score 2):

Whether by hand, by calculator or by Wolfram Alpha, it is clear that ***your*** calculation is correct.

My guess is that there is a typo or misprint in the answer provided in your linked document.